# Stor port driver and Pagefile.sys

Tags: ram, pagefile

Can the storport driver know if the Read/Write command request which has come to it, is it because of a Paging out request from the physical RAM or Paging in request to the RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a way to find if the request is from Paging I/O or not.
The API is StorPortGetRequestInfo() and in PSTOR_REQUEST_INFO  you will get to know what kind of request it is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/storport/nf-storport-storportgetrequestinfo